# Combining and Caching multiple JavaScript files in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Either I had a bad dream recently or I am just too stupid to google, but I remember that someone somewhere wrote that ASP.net has a Function which allows "merging" multiple JavaScript files automatically and only delivering one file to the client, thus reducing the number of HTTP Requests.

Server Side, you still kept all the individual .js files, but the Runtime itself then creates one big JavaScript file which is then included in the script-tag instead and can be properly cached etc.

In case that this function really exists and is not just a product of my imagination, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. For those wondering where to get the Profiler from the video:

http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=13356

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's called [Script Combining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837190.aspx). There is a video example from asp.net explaining it [here](http://www.asp.net/Learn/3.5-SP1/video-296.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

you can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HttpCombine.aspx) an usefull article for it

Answer (score 3):

.Net 4.5 have inbuilt support for [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: That's the answer.