# Best/efficient way to include JavaScript when using User Controls

Tags: javascript, vb.net, performance

I'm to .NET and all the associated cool stuff you can do, but am wondering about efficiency with User Controls and JS includes.

My user controls are mainly made up with an ascx display page and .vb.ascx code behind, as is customary with the code-behind coding style of .NET, which is great for coding simplicity although it does double then bear of files required. However, as I understand it, the server compiles these and returns the HTML efficiently.

Where the Control requires JavaScript, as I'm developing, I am making external JS files for each User Control with the same name, so the user controls consist of 'controlName.ascx, controlName.vb.ascx, controlName.js'

If a page requested by the user contains several User Controls the browser will be requesting multiple JS files, probably a master page JS file, jQuery AND each required file for the respective Controls.

This approach makes sense to me whilst developing and as everything's all kept nice and neat,  making problem solving easy, but when it goes live there'll be loads of get requests from the browser,  given that each time the browser gets a file, even the process of requesting the file to check if its cached or not must take some time.

Would I be best off including my JS inline in the ascx files, or code behind, directly inserting the script, or what is the 'correct' way to handle these multiple files to reduce get requests from the browser.

I'm using CSS sprites for buttons and stuff for the same reason, so wondering what to do with JS files. In my case CSS is generally handled by classes in the primary pages, so these are not an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining and Caching multiple JavaScript files in ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937/combining-and-caching-multiple-javascript-files-in-asp-net)

Comment: Hmm. Ok, apologies, didn't spot that, however... The control referenced from that question is for .NET 3. Unfortunately I'm currently bound to .NET 2.0 by my hosting.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1525305.aspx/1) you can still use `ScriptManager` if you install a set of "ASP.Net 2.0 AJAX extensions".

Comment: Yes, thanks, from those links I also found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488552.aspx which looks helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think I was confused by the downloadable control linked from the first article you suggested. I'll have a play with script manager later :-)

Answer (score 0):

We actually built a control on top of ScriptManager that automatically extracts all of the js from all controls on a page, including scriptresource.axd and stores them in a single cached file. This has greatly improved performance and reduced maintenance work since it is automated. We built this starting in .Net 2.0, so I am not sure if ScriptManager now provides the same functionality, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Here is our implementation of this class:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.SessionState

Public Class OurScriptManager
    Inherits ScriptManager
    Implements IRequiresSessionState

    Private m_ScriptBuilder As New StringBuilder
    'Private m_sSessionIndex As String = ""
    Private m_cScripts As List(Of ScriptReference)
    Private m_fIsCached As Boolean
    Private m_sScriptName As String = ""
    Private m_sScriptFileName As String = ""

    Const CACHED_SCRIPTS_DIR As String = "/scriptcache/"

    Public Sub New()
        ' default constructor
    End Sub

    Public Property ScriptName() As String
        Get
            Return m_sScriptName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_sScriptName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property ScriptFileName() As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_sScriptFileName) Then
                m_sScriptFileName = "~" & CACHED_SCRIPTS_DIR & Me.ScriptName & ".js"
            End If

            Return m_sScriptFileName
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

        MyBase.OnInit(e)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ScriptName) Then
            Me.ScriptName = Me.Page.ToString
        End If

        ' this compiled script should be cached on the server
        ' check for the file, if it exists, load that file instead of generating it
        If Configuration.HasPageScriptBeenCached(Me.ScriptFileName) AndAlso File.Exists(Me.Page.Server.MapPath(Me.ScriptFileName)) Then
            m_fIsCached = True
        Else
            m_cScripts = New List(Of ScriptReference)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnResolveScriptReference(ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceEventArgs)
        Try
            MyBase.OnResolveScriptReference(e)

            If Not m_fIsCached Then
                ' First, check to make sure this script should be loaded
                Dim fIsFound As Boolean

                For Each oXref As ScriptReference In m_cScripts
                    If oXref.Assembly = e.Script.Assembly AndAlso oXref.Name = e.Script.Name AndAlso oXref.Path = e.Script.Path Then
                        fIsFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                ' If this script is found within the list of scripts that this page uses, add the script to the scripthandler.aspx js output
                If Not fIsFound Then
                    Dim oReference As ScriptReference
                    Dim oElement As ScriptReference
                    Dim fIsPathBased As Boolean

                    oElement = e.Script

                    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(oElement.Path) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oElement.Name) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(oElement.Assembly) Then
                        ' If resource belongs to System.Web.Extensions.dll, it does not
                        ' provide assembly info that's why hard-coded assembly name is
                        ' written to get it in profiler
                        oElement.Assembly = "System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                    End If

                    'check to see what type of script this is
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oElement.Path) Then
                        ' this script is a physical file
                        oReference = New ScriptReference(oElement.Path)
                        fIsPathBased = True

                    ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oElement.Assembly) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oElement.Name) Then
                        ' this script is generated by an assembly
                        oReference = New ScriptReference(oElement.Name, oElement.Assembly)

                    Else
                        ' Couldn't find script, so bail to allow standard processing to take place.
                        Return

                    End If

                    If Not fIsPathBased Then
                        Dim sUrl As String
                        Dim oRequest As HttpRequest
                        Dim sScriptResourcePath As String

                        sUrl = GetUrl(oReference)
                        sScriptResourcePath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}", Context.Request.Url.Scheme, "://", Context.Request.Url.Host, ":", Context.Request.Url.Port, "/", Context.Request.ApplicationPath, "/ScriptResource.axd")

                        oRequest = New HttpRequest("scriptresource.axd", sScriptResourcePath, sUrl.Substring(sUrl.IndexOf("?"c) + 1))

                        Try
                            Using oWriter As New StringWriter(m_ScriptBuilder)
                                Dim oHandler As IHttpHandler = New System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler

                                oHandler.ProcessRequest(New HttpContext(oRequest, New HttpResponse(oWriter)))
                            End Using
                        Catch theException As Exception
                            Call ReportError(theException)
                            ' Since we couldn't automatically process this, just bail so that standard processing takes over
                            Return
                        End Try
                    Else
                        ' If this script is from a file, open the file and load the
                        ' contents of the file into the compiled js variable
                        Dim sAbsolutePath As String

                        sAbsolutePath = Context.Server.MapPath(oElement.Path)
                        Try
                            If System.IO.File.Exists(sAbsolutePath) Then
                                Using oReader As New StreamReader(sAbsolutePath, True)
                                    m_ScriptBuilder.Append(oReader.ReadToEnd())
                                End Using
                            Else
                                Throw New Exception("File " & sAbsolutePath & " does not exist")
                            End If
                        Catch theException As Exception
                            Call ReportError(theException, New ExtraErrorInformation("File", sAbsolutePath))
                            ' Since we couldn't automatically process this, just bail so that standard processing takes over
                            Return
                        End Try
                    End If

                    m_ScriptBuilder.AppendLine()

                    ' add this script to the script reference library
                    Dim oNewElement As New ScriptReference

                    oNewElement.Name = e.Script.Name.ToString()
                    oNewElement.Assembly = e.Script.Assembly.ToString()
                    oNewElement.Path = e.Script.Path.ToString()

                    m_cScripts.Add(oNewElement)
                End If
            End If

            ' a script filename is provided for caching
            e.Script.Assembly = String.Empty
            e.Script.Name = String.Empty
            e.Script.Path = Me.ScriptFileName
        Catch theException As Exception
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ReportError(theException))
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

        MyBase.Render(writer)

        If Not m_fIsCached Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ScriptName) Then
                ' Save script to file for caching
                Using fsFile As New FileStream(Me.Page.Server.MapPath(Me.ScriptFileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
                    Using oWriter As New StreamWriter(fsFile)
                        oWriter.Write(m_ScriptBuilder.ToString)
                        oWriter.Flush()
                        oWriter.Close()
                    End Using
                    fsFile.Close()
                End Using

                ' Record that the script file has been cached
                Configuration.RecordPageScriptCached(Me.ScriptFileName)
            End If
            m_ScriptBuilder = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetUrl(ByVal oReference As ScriptReference) As String
        ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(oReference.Path) Then
            Try
                Dim oMethod As MethodInfo

                oMethod = oReference.GetType.GetMethod("GetUrl", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
                If oMethod IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return DirectCast(oMethod.Invoke(oReference, New Object() {Me, False}), String)
                Else
                    Return String.Empty
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return String.Empty
            End Try
        Else
            Return Me.ResolveClientUrl(oReference.Path)
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

In the above code, ReportError logs the exception to the event log and/or file; you can replace this with your own mechanism.

Here is the Configuration code:

```
Private Shared m_cCachedPageScripts As Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

''' <summary>
''' This method is used to determine whether or not the script for the page has been cached. 
''' This is used for script combining.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sKey"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function HasPageScriptBeenCached(ByVal sKey As String) As Boolean
    ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

    SyncLock CacheSyncObject
        If m_cCachedPageScripts IsNot Nothing AndAlso m_cCachedPageScripts.Contains(sKey) Then
            Return True
        End If
    End SyncLock

End Function
''' <summary>
''' This method is used to record the fact that the page script has been cached.
''' This is used for script combining.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sKey"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Sub RecordPageScriptCached(ByVal sKey As String)
    ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

    SyncLock CacheSyncObject
        If m_cCachedPageScripts Is Nothing Then
            m_cCachedPageScripts.Add(sKey)
        End If
        m_cCachedPageScripts.Add(sKey)
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Comment: Been ages since I asked this question... coming back to it now! Your code, once again, looks superb. I don't understand much of it, but still, it looks great! I'm having an issue with a couple of variables which are giving `not declared` errors, since I'm not sure what they are I'm not sure how to sort that out. `ReportError`, `ExtraErrorInformation` and `CacheSyncObject` are showing these errors. Wondering if in fact I'm meant to make my own methods here?  Also, how is this implemented, is it entirely automated, or a reference required in the Control files?